# Spring - wire component from another project or jar

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

Apologies if this is a basic question, but I'm quite new to using Spring.

I have 2 maven projects set up in Eclipse, both using Spring.  I would like one project to use a Spring @Service in the other project.  And I am attempting to do this by annotating a member variable with the @Resource annotation.  I have added a dependency on the other project in the pom.xml.

However when running this Spring is not finding the class I want to use in the other project.  Is there something else I need to do in order for Spring to find objects in the other project?  It works fine when all the code is in one project, so do I need to tell it to scan the other project somehow?

I've tried adding a @ComponentScan() but that hasn't helped.

EDIT:  To answer the questions that people have asked of my problem.  Apologies again if I am doing something fundamentally wrong with Spring or if this is basic stuff.

So, I have 2 Maven projects, both created using the Spring Tool Suite as Spring Starter Projects.  Neither are web projects though, one is to be command line tool and the other is a library to be used by that tool and probably other projects when I get to them.  Therefore both are being created as JAR files.

The tool has a dependency in the pom.xml on the project that is the library.  It builds fine, I can get Maven to create a JAR file for it etc. As they are both Maven projects they both have the standard Maven file structure with the Java code I am after in a package in "src/main/java".

The tool is run using:

```
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

and this works fine when all the classes I am wiring together are in the same project.  Now I have moved some of these classes out in to another project it no longer finds them.

Next, I am currently only using Java annotations to configure spring, not XML. So I don't have the XML:

```
<context:annotation:config/>
```

present anywhere. Is this XML needed to achieve what I want to do here?

Finally, here is the stack trace I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.spormeon.adysis.openxdataretriever.services.OpenXDataHandler com.spormeon.adysis.openxdataretriever.Application.openxDataRetriever; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openXDataHandler': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.spormeon.adysis.aws.dynamodb.loaders.InventoryReportLoader] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at com.spormeon.adysis.openxdataretriever.Application.main(Application.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.spormeon.adysis.openxdataretriever.services.OpenXDataHandler com.spormeon.adysis.openxdataretriever.Application.openxDataRetriever; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openXDataHandler': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.spormeon.adysis.aws.dynamodb.loaders.InventoryReportLoader] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openXDataHandler': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.spormeon.adysis.aws.dynamodb.loaders.InventoryReportLoader] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
... 17 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.spormeon.adysis.aws.dynamodb.loaders.InventoryReportLoader] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:457)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:559)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
... 28 more
```

Comment: Can you show the package structure and structure of the beans in order to better understand what is going on?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace. Error could be there's either no implementing bean or more than one implementation, or maybe the bean is not being scanned for some reason. Please provide as context as possible.

Comment: I have edited the question to hopefully provide the detail you are after.

Comment: It would help show the packages you are using for the two projects and more specifically the packages of the Spring components as well as the component scanning you are using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the help but I have actually discovered what I was doing wrong!

I was using the @ComponentScan annotation, but not specifying the package in the other Maven project.

Adding that in gets everything working as I require.

Answer (score 1):

If this a web project (WAR or EAR) then make sure the dependencies are present in the WEB-INF/lib directory. Also post your application config. Do you have the following present in there.

```
<context:annotation:config/>
```

Comment: I have edited the question to hopefully provide the detail you are after.