# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException coming even though Bean is created via @Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The same question has been asked before. But I could not figure it out in my case. I am facing the below exception:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 
[com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate]
```

The MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate is created using this:

```java
@Bean
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() throws Exception {           
    return new MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate(datasource());
}
```

The above part is in another project (say B) and I am using that artifact (B) using maven in another project (say A). In A, I am autowiring like the below:

```java
@Autowired
private MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

The strange thing is that while I am deploying the code in server it is working properly. But when I am running it from local it is not running.

**Full stacktrace:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: spring
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:553) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:344) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717) ~[jetty-server-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95) ~[jetty-server-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282) ~[jetty-server-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at com.betterknow.connector.core.AbstractRunner.startNewServer(AbstractRunner.java:298) [connector-core-0.3.12.jar:na]
    at com.betterknow.connectonce.runner.ConnectOnceRunner.runOverride(ConnectOnceRunner.java:77) [connectonce-connector-core-0.7.17.jar:na]
    at com.betterknow.connector.core.AbstractRunner.run(AbstractRunner.java:179) [connector-core-0.3.12.jar:na]
    at com.betterknow.connectonce.runner.ConnectOnceMain.main(ConnectOnceMain.java:16) [connectonce-connector-core-0.7.17.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entitiesCache': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntityCacheLoader com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntitiesCache.entityCacheLoader; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityCacheLoader': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntityCacheLoader.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) ~[javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:532) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntityCacheLoader com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntitiesCache.entityCacheLoader; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityCacheLoader': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntityCacheLoader.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityCacheLoader': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntityCacheLoader.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntityCacheLoader.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
10:27:10.197 [main] ERROR c.b.c.runner.ConnectOnceRunner - Failed to start main Spring http listener
javax.servlet.ServletException: spring
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:553) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:344) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717) ~[jetty-server-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95) ~[jetty-server-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282) ~[jetty-server-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at com.betterknow.connector.core.AbstractRunner.startNewServer(AbstractRunner.java:298) [connector-core-0.3.12.jar:na]
    at com.betterknow.connectonce.runner.ConnectOnceRunner.runOverride(ConnectOnceRunner.java:77) ~[connectonce-connector-core-0.7.17.jar:na]
    at com.betterknow.connector.core.AbstractRunner.run(AbstractRunner.java:179) [connector-core-0.3.12.jar:na]
    at com.betterknow.connectonce.runner.ConnectOnceMain.main(ConnectOnceMain.java:16) [connectonce-connector-core-0.7.17.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entitiesCache': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntityCacheLoader com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntitiesCache.entityCacheLoader; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityCacheLoader': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntityCacheLoader.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) ~[javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:532) ~[jetty-servlet-8.1.14.v20131031.jar:8.1.14.v20131031]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntityCacheLoader com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntitiesCache.entityCacheLoader; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityCacheLoader': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntityCacheLoader.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityCacheLoader': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntityCacheLoader.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate com.betterknow.connectonce.connector.peoplesoft.jdbc.cache.EntityCacheLoader.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.betterknow.connectonce.jdbc.MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the factory method return type to `MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate`

Comment: Already tried doing that. But still it  is failing. @sfiss

Comment: There is no point marking it Component because I am creating a bean using Bean annotation. @Aniket

Comment: Are you component-scanning Project B?

Comment: `@Bean` without `@Component` won't be picked up, annotate your class with `@Component`.

Comment: Ensure you are scanning path to project B https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945106/spring-wire-component-from-another-project-or-jar

Comment: @Somebody Are you sure. I though I have to annote the class using Configuration annotation instead of Component annotation

Answer (score 0):

Your bean is of type `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`:

```
    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() throws Exception {           
        return new MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate(datasource());
    }
```

But you try to inject bean of type: `MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate`.

You need to either inject bean of type `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`:

```
    @Autowired // Field injection is not recommended
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

or change bean type to `MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate` in its definition:

```
    @Bean
    public MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() throws Exception {           
        return new MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate(datasource());
    }
```

> The strange thing is that while I am deploying the code in server it is working properly. But when I am running it from local it is not running.

This is really strange, because it shouldn't work, probably you deploy another artifact or you do some improper testing.

Comment: I have already tried what you have said and done mvn clean install. But I am still getting exception

Answer (score 0):

change

```
@Autowired
private MeasuringNamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

to

```
@Autowired
 private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```